# How would I find the minimum position of 1 going by column in a a list of data frames?

Tags: r

I am trying to find the minimum position i.e. the leftmost of the first 1 by column in a list of binary data frames. I have used the following to get the first 1 by row which works but when I try something similar for column I get the same output. Anyone any suggestions as to what could be wrong or what I should try?

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
file_list <- lapply(files, read.table)

first_1 <- sapply(file_list, function(x) min(which(t(x) == 1, arr.ind = T)))
```

Comment: Try `sapply(file_list, function(x) max.col(x == 1, 'first'))` gives column position for each row in the list of data.frames.  If it is the other way, take the `t`ransspose and apply `max.col`

Comment: the first code, should get the column index by row.  If it is for the whole. dataset.  then `i1 <- which(x == 1, arr.ind = TRUE); i1[,2][which.min(i1[,1])]`

Comment: @akrun this outputs as follows for example, one data frame outputs ... [1,] 1 [2,] 1 [3,] 1 [4,] 1 [5,] 1 [6,] 35. I just want it to output the minimum position of 1 going by column for each dataframe not for column position for each row? For example, my code above outputs just one number i.e. 4 for example which would be the minimum position of 1 going by row (row 4).

Comment: Do you need `lapply(file_list, function(x) {i1 <- which(x == 1, arr.ind = TRUE); i1[,2][which.min(i1[,1])]})` where `file_list <- list(data.frame(col1 = c(5, 3, 1, 2, 3), col2 = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 4)), data.frame(col1 = c(5, 3, 2, 2, 1), col2 = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 4)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we can direcly get the minimum column index by creating a logical vector with `colSums`

```
sapply(file_list, function(x) which(colSums(x == 1) > 0)[1])
```

#### data

```
file_list <- list(data.frame(col1 = c(5, 3, 1, 2, 3), col2 = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 4)),
            data.frame(col1 = c(5, 3, 2, 2, 1), col2 = c(3, 4, 5, 1, 4)))
```

Comment: From your example here should 1 not be outputted for both sets because the minimum value of 1 going by column is in the first column for both data frames? It outputs as 1 for the first one in your list and 2 for the second one @akrun